# Xamarin SkiaSharp scroll and pintch

Tags: xamarin, skiasharp

I have created a simple app that use **SkiaSharp**. I have put the **SKCanvasView** inside a Scroll view so I can scroll it. Can somebody help me to find is there a way to zoom it with the gesture?
Thanks.

Comment: Which platform? iOS, Android or Forms? if Android: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/touch/android-touch-walkthrough

Comment: But, be careful using SKCanvasView in SCrollView for big canvas. SKCanvasView can take a lot of memory for big images.